# Is it possible to run Fastlane/Snapshot on device instead of Simulator?

Tags: ios, device, simulator, snapshot, fastlane

Recently, I started using Fastlane's Snapshot tool. However, Snapshot seems to run only in Simulator environment and that creates a problem for me since the app I'm working on is interacting with Whatsapp and Whatsapp cannot be used on simulator. Thus, I cannot take screenshots of some of the interactive steps of my app with Snapshot.

My question is: Are there any settings in Snapfile or some other ways of having Snapshot run on an actual device and not the simulators? Or there is no such option and I would need to think of setting my UI tests differently?

Thank you!

Comment: I assume the Snapshot was never intended to be used on device, but maybe someone also knows the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into Fastlane's issue board, found out similar question posted there. So indeed, it is not possible to run Snapshot on a real device atm, but the possibility of having such feature is currently being looked into (dev's comment posted on May 19).
Link to the Git post: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/1635